# Always open files in new frame (osx)

Tags: frames

Whenever I double-click files on finder to open them using emacs, they open in existing buffers. Instead I would like them to open in separate frames by default.

It seems as though many others have also queried this issue on StackExchange but I still haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer.

I've been trying to use display-buffer-alist and display-buffer-pop-up-frame but the documentation for this is very confusing and I couldn't find the right phrasing for my init.el file.

I'm using OS X El Capitan 10.11.3, and Emacs 24.5.1 with this version: https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port

Comment: 1) Tell the Emacs developers that you find this particular doc confusing, and why, so they can improve it - `M-x report-emacs-bug`. 2)  Try setting option `pop-up-frames` to `t`, as a start.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean adding: (setq pop-up-frames t) to the init.el file? This doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. When you use "-other-window" commands, it should cause buffers (not just file buffers, though) to be shown in a separate frame instead of a separate window. It's only a start.

Comment: From http://superuser.com/a/431601/4910 `(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)`